# -1 < 2 == 1 False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I am comparing an equation in python:

```
-1 < 2 == 1
```

it gives `False` as output

The Left Hand side of the `==`:

`-1 < 2` which evaluates to `True`

Right Hand side of the `==` is:

`1`

On comparing `L.H.S==R.H.S`

`True==1`

which should evaluate to `True`?

Comment: It works when using brackets `(-1 < 2) == 1` so I think the `==` normally has priority over `<` for whatever reason

Comment: I should say that `-1 < 2 == 1` *(even if add parentheses to make it work as expected)* is something that is unlikely to be used in real code, so the problem is somewhat artificial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs: [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)

*Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).*

So the equation becomes:

```
-1 < 2  and 2 == 1
True and False
False
```